# Failing to stub somewhat complex method calls with Mockito (Scala)

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, specs2

Today, my colleague and myself were fighting with difficulties to stub a method of a dependency in one of out unit tests.

The service class under test looks something like this:

```
class MongoChecklistResultRepository @Inject()(system: ActorSystem,
                                               reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi,
                                               checklistResultVersioningService: ChecklistResultVersioningService)
...
override def count(): Future[Int] = collection(ResultsCollectionName).count()
...

private def collection(name: String): JSONCollection =
    reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection](name)
    }
```

And inside the test that should test `count` method, we are trying to mock the `collection` object that we getting from driver and eventually stub it's count method:

```
doReturn(Future.successful(1)).when(jsonCollection).count()
```

All looks valid, but when executed, `collection(ResultsCollectionName).count()` always retuns null (in simple words the stub is not working.

if we look on the count method os generic collection, we'll see much more complex signature:

```
def count[H](selector: Option[pack.Document] = None, limit: Int = 0, skip: Int = 0, hint: Option[H] = None)(implicit h: H => CountCommand.Hint, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int]
```

And I beleive, this is the exact reason why the stubbing does not work.

We also tried doing this:

```
doReturn(Future.successful(1)).when(jsonCollection).count[MockCommand](None, 0, 0, None)
```

Also, didn't help. How can create reliable stub for these kind of methods?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to pass implicit parameters as well.

Comment: Right, I tried it too. Implicit `ExecutionContext` is not a problem but, for some reason, I could not mock or instantiate this `implicit h: H => CountCommand.Hint`. And this is where we got stuck.

Comment: try `null.asInstanceOf[Any => CountCommand.Hint]`

Comment: You mean like that: `implicit val h = null.asInstanceOf[Any => CountCommand.Hint]` in the test?

Comment: Yes, or just pass explicitly. Another idea is `doReturn(Future.successful(1)).when(jsonCollection).count[MockCommand](None, 0, 0, None)(any[Any => CountCommand.Hint], any[ExecutionContext])` that is probably more likely to work. I think it would work to leave off default parameters like this `doReturn(Future.successful(1)).when(jsonCollection).count[MockCommand]()(any[Any => CountCommand.Hint], any[ExecutionContext])`

Comment: Ok, we'll try this tomorrow. Thanks.